# How to change stack depth limits in /etc/security/limits.d/ and have the changes apply to services at boot

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, ansible, ulimit

**My system**

- Series of Ubuntu 14.04.5 (x86_64) Servers, kept updated
- My application required I increase stack depth for postgres
- I created a file in */etc/security/limits.d/myapplication.conf*
- The *myapplication.conf* file has the line: `*                -       stack           131072`
- Note that 131072KB == 128MB
- Upon making this *myapplication.conf* file, my `ulimit -s` returns: `131072`
- I then edited my */etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf* file and appended the line: `max_stack_depth = 126MB`

**My problem**

During boot, the following message appears:

```
 * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2018-01-24 09:27:53 MST LOG:  invalid value for parameter "max_stack_depth": 129024
2018-01-24 09:27:53 MST DETAIL:  "max_stack_depth" must not exceed 7680kB.
2018-01-24 09:27:53 MST HINT:  Increase the platform's stack depth limit via "ulimit -s" or local equivalent.
2018-01-24 09:27:53 MST FATAL:  configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf" contains errors
 * Starting Mount network filesystems                                    [ OK ]
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server        * Stopping Mount networ[ OK ]systems
                                                                                             [fail]
```

This in turn causes my application service to then fail, as I depend on my databases. After boot, if I start the postgres service, it's fine:

```
dev@wipn:~$ sudo service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             [ OK ] 
dev@wipn:~$
```

My guess is that the effects of */etc/security/limits.d/myapplication.conf* are only applied at a stage during boot that's after when my system tries to start postgres. So, perhaps an obvious solution is to just change when I start postgres, that's fine and I can handle that.

**My Question**

What's a way to change the kernel's stack depth, such that I need only make minimal alterations to my servers?

I want something as clean as possible. I want it to withstand upgrades and preferably be applicable to other distros. I manage my stuff through Ansible plays, so I'd rather write one clean play for this.

It may simply be the case that changing start order of my services is *the best* resolution. Anyone out there know of other suitable options?

**Things I've tried**

Here's a list of some of the things I've tried, without success.

In */etc/security/limits.d/myapplication.conf*:

- `postgres                -       stack           131072`
- `*                  -       stack           131072
  root                -       stack           131072`

Answer (score 1):

Until someone can give me a clean solution, this is what I've come up with, and it sucks. I won't accept it as THE answer to my question, but here it is (gags). At least it works.

**Background**

Seems that changes to */etc/security/limits.** never impact services, but rather stuff being executed from the shell. So, that kind of makes my changes in */etc/security/limits.** quite meaningless. (*insert cussing here*). I've now deleted my */etc/security/limits.d/myapplication.conf*.

**Changing Stack Size limits for postgres**

This is a garbage solution. I hate it.

I've edited my "/usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions", specifically the *start()* function, to appear as:

```
...
# start all clusters of version $1
# output according to Debian Policy for init scripts
start() {
    ulimit -s 131072    #JTS: To avoid Issue #XYZ 

    # create socket directory
    if [ -d /var/run/postgresql ]; then
        chmod 2775 /var/run/postgresql
    else
    ...
```

Obviously I've added the ulimit line. It's disgusting to me to modify this file because I expect it to be perpetually changed by updates. At least I have an Ansible rule to enforce it exists.

**My Ansible solution**

Here's the Ansible task I've created to enforce this config change for me:

```
- blockinfile:
    dest: /usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions
    block: |
          ulimit -s 131072
    backup: yes
    insertafter: '^start\(\) \{'
    state: present
```

This Ansible task results in the function looking like this:

```
...
# start all clusters of version $1
# output according to Debian Policy for init scripts
start() {
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
ulimit -s 131072
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
    # create socket directory
    if [ -d /var/run/postgresql ]; then
       ...
```

**Of Note: Upstart Services Ignore */etc/security/limits***

Seems that */etc/security/limits.** is ignorred by Upstart, which Ubuntu 14.04 uses. My application service actually uses upstart and one can insert a line for upstart that looks like:

```
limit stack <softlimit> <hardlimit>
```

Ubuntu switched to systemd after 14.04, so this upstart tid-bit will fade in to irrelevance.

This isn't relevant to my question because on 14.04, *postgresql* is not managed by upstart.

Answer (score 0):

So I came here having the same issue and perhaps you find what I did more acceptable:
My PostgreSQL runs as a systemd service.
In the service file, I ve unlimited the stack from the OS's perspective:

```
[Service]
...
LimitSTACK=infinity
```

In the postgresql.conf, I then set the following:

```
max_stack_depth = 100MB
```

This allowed to run my faulty recursive query for a few minutes, instead of a second.

I hope it helps you, event 1.5 years after your question.

(Postgresql 9.5.10 on Fedora 25)